# branch.getFirstReferringParams() always returning blank array

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I have integrated react-native-branch in my app (for Android). Everything working find except getting blank response in **branch.getFirstReferringParams()**. I want to get details from where a user redirected to play store for analytics purpose.

```
    branch.subscribe(({error, params, uri}) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error)
        return
      }
    }
    let lastParams = await branch.getLatestReferringParams()
    let installParams = await branch.getFirstReferringParams() // params from original install`
```

Comment: Could you share if you are calling getFirstReferringParams before branch.subscribe or after it? Also could you share the snippet where you are reading the link data

Comment: I'm calling getFirstReferringParams after branch.subscribe. Please see, updated my question.

Comment: @KartikShandilya plz see, I need to solve this urgent as client are goining to launch campaign.